# Transport equation - Find intersection of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, transport-equation

Given the transport equation:

$$u^2u_x + u_y = 0$$

with the initial condition $u(x, 0) = 1$ for $x \leq 0$, $u(x, 0)=0$ for $x \geq 1$ and $u(x, 0) = \sqrt{1-x}$ for $0 < x < 1$.

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{dx}{dt} = u^2 \Rightarrow h(s)^2*t + c\\
&\frac{dy}{dt} = 1 \Rightarrow t + c\\
& \frac{du}{dt} = 0 \Rightarrow h(s)
\end{align}$$

$s \leq 0$
$$\begin{align}
&x(t, s) = s + y(t, s) &\Rightarrow s = x-y\\
&y(t, s) = t &\Rightarrow t = y\\
\end{align}$$

$0 \leq s \leq 1$
$$\begin{align}
&x(t, s) = s + (1-s)*t &\Rightarrow s = \frac{x-y}{1-y}\\
&y(t, s) = y &\Rightarrow t = y\\
\end{align}$$

$s \geq 1$
$$\begin{align}
&x(t, s) = s &\Rightarrow s = x\\
&y(t, s) = y &\Rightarrow t = y\\
\end{align}$$

How can I find now the critical time where the characteristics intersect? I know the solution is $(x, y) = (1, 1)$ but I couldn't find a place that really shows how to derive it.

Comment: The solutions are given by $$u(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \le 0 \\ \sqrt{\dfrac{1-x}{1-y}}, & 0 < x < 1 \\ 0, & x \ge 1 \end{cases}$$ it should be clear now.

Comment: @mattos it is $(1, 1)$ because $\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1-y}}$ is undefined when $x,y$ tend to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems involving characteristics are a lot easier to grasp once you draw a picture. IF you divide through by $u^2$, you get the equation in the standard form of an advection equation:
$$
u_x+\frac{1}{u^2}u_y=0.
$$
From this you can derive the characteristic lines easily since the slope of the lines $y=f(x)$ is given by the coefficient of $u_y$ in the equation. In this case, the characteristics are straight lines so you can solve things graphically.

[image]